# How to calculate max, min and average in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to separate jobs with color based on conversion of what I did as follow:

```
select count(ap.id), 
       (count(ap.id)/cast(SUM(j.views) as float) * 100) as conversion,
       j.company_id 
  from applications ap 
          right join jobs j 
            on ap.job_id = j.id 
 where j.company_id = 61805
 group by j.id
```

if conversion column is greater than 75% of total average of that result, I want to create new alias column and value will be **green**. if conversion column is between 35% and 75%, column value will be **yellow** and less than 35%, column value will be **red**.

Is can be possible do in postgres as above query I've mentioned? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your query as a subquery and then use a `case` statement. Also you mentioned in the title a median not average, so which one you need?

Comment: `group by j.id` seems wrong to me.  You are doing a `LEFT JOIN` on `jobs j`, so `j.id` can be `NULL`.  Also, you don't need to select `j.company_id`; you already know it's 61805.

Comment: @JorgeCampos for average instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin I've changed to `right`, sorry. set company_id as default value is just a example.

Comment: @JorgeCampos any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are your friend:

```
SELECT count,
       conversion,
       CASE
          WHEN conversion > avg_conv * 0.75
          THEN 'green'
          WHEN conversion < avg_conv * 0.35
          THEN 'red'
          ELSE 'yellow'
       END AS color,
       company_id
FROM (SELECT count,
             conversion,
             avg(conversion) OVER () AS avg_conv,
             company_id
      FROM (SELECT count(ap.id), 
                   (count(ap.id)/cast(SUM(j.views) as float) * 100) AS conversion,
                   j.company_id 
            FROM applications ap 
               RIGHT JOIN jobs j 
                  ON ap.job_id = j.id 
            WHERE j.company_id = 61805
            GROUP BY j.company_id
           ) with_avg
     ) with_color;
```

(untested)